# How would you say "A has the meaning of B" or "A conveys B"

Tags: grammar, words

For example, if I was trying to tell someone that in English when we say "sake" it already has the implication of it being "Japanese sake", so have the "Japanese" is redundant.

My English brain wants to say `AはBの意味を持つ`, and my best guess is something with `伝える`, I'm just having a really hard time researching this.

Comment: I usually use `AはBを意味する` for sort of direct equivalences, while `AはBの意味を持つ` would also have a sort of implication that A also means some other stuff, but I don't fully understand the nuances between these and other options, so I'll let someone else answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. As Darius said, 意味する.
2. You can also use ～と言う意味合いがある (nuance)
3. As explained at [goo.jp](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/191938/m1u/%E5%90%AB%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/), you can also use ～と言う意味を含める to emphasize the subtle aspect of the nuance: 「風刺的意味を―・める」
4. More concretely, you can say ～のことを指す (indicates).

This might be acceptable, therefore:

> 英語には「アルコール」とか「リカー」という言葉がありますので、「酒」という言葉を使うときは、「日本酒」のことを指しているのです。

Answer (score 1):

The most simple method I was always taught was when giving a definition or further explanation to a term to use ～という意味だ, ということだ, or という意味がある

For example,

「名所は特に有名な所ということです」
「武士道は侍の尊敬と礼儀を表し方ということです」

I know that there are other methods out there, but it seems that for what you're trying to do this might be the simplest and most direct path.

As the other response mentioned, 含む (to include) might be a useful verb to have on hand here to suggest that when discussing *sake* that meaning is already included.

To directly translate the example that you were discussing, I might say something like this: 「酒はアルコールが入っている飲み物という意味がありますが、ある時に酒の意味に日本酒ということも含みます。」

Comment: This would have been a pretty good answer if the example sentences had been grammatical.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya why not edit in some corrections?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, I think you can also use the ...と言う意味, or 「...」って言う意味 form.

```
AはBという意味ですか？

Do you mean that A is B?
```

Comment: How is this different from what user136286 said?